# Why would I get a "BoolToRowHeightConverter is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation(WPF) project error in xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Why would I get a "BoolToRowHeightConverter is not supported in  a Windows Presentation Foundation(WPF) project error in xaml?
I was using a converter to convert rowheight to * and Auto in a grid based on the expander's IsExpanded property.

Code in xaml:

```
     <RowDefinition Height="{Binding IsExpanded, ElementName=Expander5, Converter={x:Static BoolToRowHeightConverter.Instance}}"/>
```

Code in xaml.cs:

```
    public class BoolToRowHeightConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object   parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if ((bool)value) return new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
            else
                return GridLength.Auto;

        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }


    }
```

Comment: Thanks dkozl,but this didnt solve ,got the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, [`IValueConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx)s are used like this:

a) Add a namespace in your XAML page that references your converter class... usually it looks something like this:

```
xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Converters"
```

b) Add an instance of your converter class into the `Resources` section of your page (or of `App.xaml`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Converters:BoolToRowHeightConverter x:Key="BoolToRowHeightConverter" />
    ...
</Window.Resources>
```

c) Reference your converter instance by the `x:Key` value that you gave it:

```
<RowDefinition Height="{Binding IsExpanded, ElementName=Expander5, 
    Converter={StaticResource BoolToRowHeightConverter}}" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sheridan for the detail explanation.It worked!

Answer (score 0):

You have decided to reference the value converter by using the `x:Static` markup extension (`{x:Static BoolToRowHeightConverter.Instance}`) but then you also need to provide the actual field or property that you reference (`Instance`). To do that you need to add it to the `BoolToRowHeightConverter` class:

```
public class BoolToRowHeightConverter : IValueConverter
{

  // Convert and ConvertBack methods ...

  public static readonly BoolToRowHeightConverter Instance = new BoolToRowHeightConverter();

}
```

Comment: Thank you martin ,but somehow this still didnt work.got the same error.FYI.This was my MainWindow and I have this new class in the mainwindow xaml.cs file.not sure if that matters.

Comment: You also need to make sure that you are using the right namespace. You need to declare the namespace in XAML as a prefix and then use the namespace. It is not problem that the converter is defined in `MainWindow.xaml.cs` but it is important that the converter is not a nested class inside the `MainWindow` class.

Comment: Thank you Martin for your time.your suggestions helped.